# Storing a general python object in a Blender scene

Tags: python, objects, workflow

I need to store a KDTree in my scene, preferably attached to a specific Blender object.  When storing standard Blender types associated with objects, I use

```
my_ob["my list"] = my_list
```

but a KDTree is not a primitive type, and I get the error "TypeError: only floats, ints and dicts are allowed in ID property arrays".

How can I store my KDTree so that I don't have to regenerate it many times over?  This is for an addon, so I don't want to have to save a local file and reload.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure you will have any luck. You can add a [string property](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.StringProperty) to hold a filename that holds the cached data. You could also pickle it to a [text block](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.BlendData.html#bpy.types.BlendData.texts) in blenders text editor.

Answer (score 2):

For these cases you can use `pickle` and `base64` to string.
But be aware that you need to use cKDTree according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37722991/unable-to-pickle-scipy-spatial-kdtree-objects

```
import pickle
import base64

# store kdtree
def _set_kdtree_for_object(my_obj, my_kdtree):
    pickled_kdtree = pickle.dumps(my_kdtree)
    # pickled_kdtree is binary convert it to a string
    base64encoded = base64.b64decode(pickled_kdtree).decode('utf-8')
    my_obj['my_list'] = base64encoded

# read back
def _get_kdtree_for_object(my_obj):
    base64encoded = my_obj['my_list']
    pickled_kdtree = base64.b64encode(base64encoded.encode('utf-8'))
    my_kdtree = pickle.loads(pickled_kdtree)
    return my_kdtree
```

Be aware that exceptions may happen due to different pickle implementations when python is updated in blender.

Depending on the usecase you could also use a global store on object name. This will not store the kdtree in your blend file, but you need to be able to recreate the kdtree when it is not available. This solves issues of python updates.

```
kdtree_lookup = {}

def _get_or_rebuild_kdtree_for_object(obj):
    global kdtree_lookup
    result = kdtree_lookup.get(obj)
    if result is None:
        # rebuild the kdtree
        ...
        # store it
        kdtree_lookup[obj] = result
    return result
```

You could also rebuild the kdtree's after loading of the blendfile using an handler.

Comment: Thanks for your response, this does indeed solve the question as asked.  Unfortunately, my application is for an addon, so I don't want to have to interact with saved local files.  I have updated the question accordingly.