# Sharing BVHTree across addons

Tags: python, add-on

I have an addon, "MeshLoader" that creates a BVHTree from a large mesh.My question is how do I access that BVHTree from another addon, "MeshOperator". I do not want to have to recreate the BVHTree.

In the MeshLoader addon, I tried to store the BVHtree with something like as follows:

```
bpy.context.scene.collection["my_bvh"] = bvhtree
```

but I've been getting TypeError: invalid id-property type BVHTree not supported

Comment: Hello ! Do you want to be able to interact with data created in another addon, or do you want to store this data in the blend file ? Or both ?

Comment: to interact.. to do something with the mesh, using the bvhtree created with the earlier addon

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that all I have to do is to declare the bvhtree as a global variable, as per the answer here [Storing a general python object in a Blender scene](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/103233/storing-a-general-python-object-in-a-blender-scene?rq=1)

Some sort of tracking must of course be done to determine if the geometry has been touched in between addon invocation.